# plotly: adjusting the x axis so it increases at a regular interval

Tags: graph, plotly, r-plotly

I'm very novice at this so this might be a dumb question but -
I have an csv data of a regular x and y values. The x values however - are not always increasing constantly. The graph that plotly made for me had x values and increased based on the data. the x value are dates so this causes some misinterpretation base on the graph. Is there a way to have the dates increase at regular interval in the graph?

Here's what the graph looks like(a snippet)
[image]

`Beginning and end`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data to get a [MCVE]? Are your x-data values dates?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Yes, ofcourse! I included more sample data. (and yes the xvalues are dates)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert your x-values to `datetime` objects first. Plotly will then recognize the x-values as date values and plot them accordingly.

```
from datetime import datetime
import plotly

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
x = ['1961/04/12',
     '1961/04/13',
     '1961/05/04',
     '1961/06/06',
     '1961/07/20',
     '1961/07/22',
     '1961/08/05',
     '1961/08/07',
     '1962/02/19']

y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]

# convert your x-values to date
d = []
for t in x:
    t = [int(t) for t in t.split('/')]
    d.append(datetime(*t))

data = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=d, y=y,line=dict(shape='hv'))]
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image]